# How to create/initialise default Realtime Database instance in a Firebase project using CLI?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to set up a Firebase project that needs a default Realtime Database instance using **non-interactive** CLI.

I've tried deploying the rules:

```
❯ firebase deploy --only database

Error: It looks like you haven't created a Realtime Database instance in this project before.
Please run firebase init database to create your default Realtime Database instance.
```

but `firebase init` is an interactive command, so I can't use it in my CI pipeline.

An attempt to use `firebase database:instances:create` command also fails with the same message:

```
❯ firebase database:instances:create default

Error: It looks like you haven't created a Realtime Database instance in this project before.
Please run firebase init database to create your default Realtime Database instance.
```

I've tried googling for anything around creating default realtime database instances, but can't find anything besides going the interactive CLI way or doing it through the console - both of which are ill-suited for CI.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm after without resorting to interactive tools?

Answer (score 1):

From the second line of that second error message:

> Please run firebase init database to create your default Realtime Database instance.

It seems that you'll need to run `firebase init database` to create the initial/default database instance for the project. After that you can run `firebase database:instances:create` to create additional instances.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that - but my goal is to have the entire process unattended for CI (in a new project not touched by human hand). Running anything manually defies the purpose.

Comment: `firebase init database` can also be run non-interactively, can't it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by starting the Realtime Database from the Firebase web console.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).